# Is there a Linux analogue for MSVC's linker switch /VERBOSE?

Tags: linker, ld

On MSVC when I add the linker switch /VERBOSE I'm able to track the link resolution of individual functions, and thereby the reason that libraries are linked in:
[image]

`-Wl,--verbose` doesn't do the same for Linux linkers, and I can't find anything else in ld/lld/gold/mold that does. Is there anything similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case this is of interest to others:
On ld and compatible linkers, `--cref` achieves similar results.  Here's a snippet of the result of building the above code with `g++ -Wl,--cref tst.cpp`:

```
Cross Reference Table

Symbol                                            File
CXXABI_1.3                                        /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
CXXABI_1.3.1                                      /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
CXXABI_1.3.10                                     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
CXXABI_1.3.11                                     /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
...

std::cout                                         /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
                                                  /tmp/cc8SMng2.o
std::cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4                            /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
std::cout@GLIBCXX_3.4                             /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
...
std::ios_base::Init::Init()                       /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/libstdc++.so
                                                  /tmp/cc8SMng2.o
...
```

The first line for each symbol is the location of its definition, the next lines (for the same symbol) are locations referencing it.